# Is there any audio hub that works similar to an HDMI switch?

Tags: audio

I am looking for something similar to my HDMI switch, but for audio.  I have a few devices on my desk but only one set of speakers. I would like to find a switch that allows me to plug them all into the switch, with the switch outputting to the speakers.

Clarification: My speakers are Logitech Z623.  I am using the standard 3.5mm audio cables that connect that to my computer.  I have audio that can also come in from my tablet (again, a standard audio cable plugging into the headphone jack to the switch). I have my PS3 connected to my monitor via HDMI, and will have another standard audio cable from the headphone port of the monitor going to the switch.

I do not know what the correct "name" is for the standard audio cable - TRS, phono, whatever, it is just the standard audio cable that most people use to connect to the computer.

Comment: Audio switches do exist. As for the downvote. I found hundreds of them by doing a google search. [TOSLink Digial Audio Switch](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA24G0P59036&cm_re=toslink_switch-_-82-196-080-_-Product)

Comment: That outputs to TOSLINK.  I have not found that just uses regular audio cables.

Comment: You were not specific in your original question.  I assumed the audio devices support TOSLINk optical connections.  What do you mean by "regular" audio cables exactly?  Update your question, without this information, it cannot be answered.

Comment: Clarified.  I keep finding things that would work if my audio cables were RCA, but unfortunately nothing like the simple audio cables that i would use for instance to plug my phone into my car.